# QueryDsql build a query with no booleanbuilder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, querydsl

I have a queryDsl booleanbuilder query, because of many if's in my code:

```
 private Page<QA> query(Pageable pageable, QAFilter filter) {

    QA qa = QA.a;
    BooleanBuilder bb = new BooleanBuilder();


    if (StringUtils.qaNotBlank(filter.getParam())) {
        bb.and(likePredicate(qa.param, filter.getCode()));
    }

    if (StringUtils.qaNotBlank(filter.get2param())) {
        bb.and(qa.locationCode.eq(filter.2param()));
    }

    if (sth == true) {
        bb.or(qa.joinedObject.any().field.eq(filter.param));
    }

    return repo.findAll(bb.getValue(), pageable);
}
```

If works fine unless the "sth" is false. 
When it is true the booleanbuilder creates a subquery that checks all rows from 2 tables whick takes 2 minutes. 
I wrote my own sql and it fakes a second. So my question is how to implement my sql to HQL/DSL Querty/etc. so that if checks my if's and adds params to query. 
Like:

```
 private Page<QA> query(Pageable pageable, QAFilter filter) {

    QA qa = QA.a;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuesry();
    query.leftjoin(myobiects);

    if (StringUtils.qaNotBlank(filter.getParam())) {
        query.where(likePredicate(qa.param, filter.getCode()));
    }

    if (StringUtils.qaNotBlank(filter.get2param())) {
        query.where(qa.locationCode.eq(filter.2param()));
    }

    if (sth == true) {
        query.where(qa.joinedObject.any().field.eq(filter.param));
    }

    return repo.findInDB(query, pageable);
}
```

Now how to connet the objects with OR, AND etc.

Answer (score 0):

The BooleanBuilder instance can be used as the predicate of query by invoking where:

```
query.where(bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the question was about how to speed up the query. I wondered how about changing the code etc, but finally I decided to create an index on the foreign key (JoinedObjectTable.ForeignKeyToQA - as the  `query.where(qa.joinedObject.any()` created a subquery). So the index increased the speed from 2 min to about 0,05 sek.